# Elasticsearch aggregations with filter match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a document with a collection of nested documents:

```js
{
  "_source": {
    ...
    "groups": [
      {
        "group_id": 100,
        "parent_group_id": 1,
        "title": "Wheel",
        "parent_group_title": "Parts"
      },
      {
        "group_id": 200,
        "parent_group_id": 2,
        "title": "Seat",
        "parent_group_title": "Parts"
      }
    ]
    ...
  }
}
```

Mapping looks the next:

```js
{
  ...,

  "groups": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "group_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "parent_group_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "parent_group_title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is the next aggregation:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "groups",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "groups.title": {
                  "query": "whe"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "groups",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "groups.title": {
                      "query": "whe"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "groups": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "groups"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "titles": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "groups.title.keyword",
                "size": 5
              },
              "aggs": {
                "parents": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "groups.parent_group_title.keyword",
                    "size": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With such query I'm getting results something like the next:

```js
  "aggregations" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "doc_count" : ...,
      "groups" : {
        "doc_count" : ...,
        "titles" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : ...,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : ...,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "Seat",
              "doc_count" : 10,
              "parents" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 10,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : "Parts",
                    "doc_count" : 6
                  },
                  {
                    "key" : "Other",
                    "doc_count" : 4
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key" : "Wheel",
              "doc_count" : 3,
              "parents" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 3,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : "Parts",
                    "doc_count" : 2
                  },
                  {
                    "key" : "Other",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But what I want is that only result with key `Wheel` is to appear in the result buckets (or any other results matching to `whe` search string).

Hope the question is clear enough. What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestings or changing data structure or query?

**UPD:**
Adding a `my_custom_analyzer` for reference:

```
{
  "my_custom_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "ngram",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding"
    ],
    "char_filter": [
      "html_strip"
    ],
    "min_gram": 2,
    "max_gram": 15,
    "token_chars": [
      "letter",
      "digit"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to filter just before the `groups.title` group. This means you don't need your top-level query at all nor the `filtered`-level query.

I don't have your `my_custom_analyzer` available so I used a basic match but you get the gist:

```
GET groups/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "groups"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "titles": {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "groups.title": {
                "query": "wheel"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_title_terms": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "groups.title.keyword",
                "size": 5
              },
              "aggs": {
                "parents": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "groups.parent_group_title.keyword",
                    "size": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

There's an issue w/ your analyzer -- let's use `_analyze` to determine how `whe` would get tokenized:

```
GET groups/_analyze
{
  "text": "whe",
  "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
}
```

yielding

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "w",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "wh",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "h",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "he",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "e",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I suspect based on the token `e`, `Seats` get matched.

---

My suggestion is to use the `edge_ngram` instead of `n_gram` as follows:

```
PUT groups
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "groups": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "group_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "parent_group_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "parent_group_title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apply the mapping, reindex & you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.
I still seeing keys in the resulting bucket that doesn't match search phrase `whe` (or `wheel` doesn't matter). 
I tried to sort results in bucket by _score, but this drastically decreases performance, so this is not the way to go :(
**P.S.**: added `my_custom_analyzer` to the question body, maybe this will help.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thx for adding the analyzer.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the help @joe. Right now it is working as I expect.
So the issues appeared to be in my analyzer at the end.